# Start CUDA Debugging Invocation Issue - Value cannot be null

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, cuda, visual-studio-debugging

I guess to start:

- Platform - Win7 x64
- Framework - CUDA 5.0 RC using VS 2010
- Debugger - Nsight VS Edition 2.2

After each debugging session, I am unable to immediately debug again (if desired) as I'm presented with a Visual Studio error pop-up that states "Value Cannot be null. Parameter name: pSrcNativeVariant". If I rebuild, I am able to invoke the debugging *session* fine.

The rebuild doesn't completely rid me of this problem though. While in the debug session, if I try to open a CUDA Warp Watch window, I'm presented with the same thing.  I've never seen this error before and have not had much success at finding a solution. I'm assuming it has something to do with the way I have something configured, as there's nothing indicative of CUDA in the error (and I have not explicitly used pSrcNativeVariant). If anyone could shed some light or point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

p.s. sorry I couldn't attach the image (not enough rep)

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nsight 2.2 only supports CUDA 4.2 and 4.1. For CUDA 5.0 support, please wait for Nsight 3.0 which will come late October. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That sounds pretty strange. I would try an uninstall and reinstall. Uninstall all the CUDA stuff then VS. Then reinstall VS and Nsight (in that order). I'd download the version of Nsight that has the CUDA toolkit bundled.

Comment: Yeah, I've followed this route during my initial install phase (with CUDA 5 not being in the Nsight package). However, my installs are not in the default locations as I'm running a solid state as my primary. As a result, I threw VS/CUDA on my secondary.  Maybe this has something to do with it.

Comment: I did try the re-install route, didn't fix the issue... strange

Comment: Did you use the default locations when reinstalling?